# What do <stroke /> and <corners /> mean?

Tags: android, layout

I want to know what do exactly Stroke and Corners do in Android Studio.

This code is in drawable folder for image button in main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<shape>
    <stroke android:width="1.3dp">

    </stroke>
    <corners android:radius="30dp">

    </corners>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want an outline around your shape and to do that you can use the stroke tag. You can specify the width and color of the outline using android:width and android:color.

Since your shape is a rectangle, you can round rectangle’s corners. You can do that inside of the corners tag. You can specify the radius for all of the corners using android:radius

you can see useful Content and samples about android shapes in https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5

Answer (score 0):

stroke : define shape bolder style.
corners: Define shape corner style.
Please read this article https://www.dev2qa.com/android-shape-selector-examples/